# Как раскодировать массив байтов в строку?

Tags: c#, .net, rtf

Есть массив байтов, представляющий собой RTF-текст (с тегами), содержащий картинки. Как получить из него строку? Я использовал `Encoding.Default`, затем перегонял в `RichTextBox` и сейвил в файл - на выходе получал только текст, без вложений.

Comment: Так в чём проблема? Хочется из рича не в текст файл? Или рич не выполняет поставленной задачи?

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне хочется получить не только текст, но и содержащиеся там пикчи и прочие вложения

Comment: Какбы преобразовать в строку это только подготовка, а дальше рыться в противоречивых спеках и разбирать элементы RTF.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte_array, 0, byte_array.Length);
```

Полученный результат писать сразу в файл.

**Хотя, конечно, зависит от того каким образом Вы его закодировали.**

Comment: Нет-нет. Сама разметка RTF состоит из ASCII (Latin-1).

Comment: Ну тогда: Encoding.ASCII.GetString
Вы скажите как получили массив байт, тогда и ответ станет очевидным.

Comment: Массив байтов - тело задачи Outlook, Outlook.TaskItem, свойство RTFBody. UTF8 и ASCII выдали вместо кириллицы вопросительные знаки, в остальном все так же)

Comment: А в RichTextBox Вы получали картинки (или их там нет вовсе)?

Вам так же необходимо углубится в изучение формата RTF, я предполагаю, что картинки идут отельным двоичным кодом от текста (возможно после всего текста). И преобразовать двоичный код картинки в картинку.

Так же, если это чистый rtf, то переsaveив его в файл, должен получится полноценный *.RTF.

**Вы так же не отметили куда это все необходимо положить.**